# How can I add a function to Swift as an extension to String to simplify usage

Tags: string, swift

I have a function coded as:

```
func deleteEnclosedString(s: String, startString s1:String, endString s2: String) -> String { 
}
```

I would like to create a `class` which is sub-classed to `String` in which I define a function and use it as follows:

```
var myString = "A [typical] string"
myString.deleteEnclosedString(startString: "[", endString: "]")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it in the following way:

```
extension String {
   func deleteEnclosedString (startString s1: String, endString s2: String) -> String {
       return self.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\(s1)(.*)\(s2)", withString: "", options: .RegularExpressionSearch, range: nil)
   }    
}
```

Extensions add new functionality to an existing class, structure, or enumeration type. This includes the ability to extend types for which you do not have access to the original source code (known as retroactive modeling).

The you can call the above function in the following way :

```
var rest = "A [typical] string".deleteEnclosedString(startString: "\\[", endString: "\\]")
```

The above function is an example of removing the word inside the passed `startString` and `endString` using regular expressions, it's just for reference nothing else.

I hope this help you.

Comment: Thank you, Victor. This is a great help. Would have taken me a lot of effort to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use String method componentsSeparatedByString and return the first and last components as follow:

```
var myString = "A [typical] string"

extension String {
    func deleteEnclosedString(#from: String, to: String ) -> String {
        return componentsSeparatedByString(from).first! + componentsSeparatedByString(to).last!
    }
}
println( myString.deleteEnclosedString(from: "[", to: "]") )  // "A  string"
```